# IE7-js alongside minified CSS file breaks all CSS in IE7

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a web app that uses the [IE7js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) library to add additional CSS features to lower versions of IE. I also use a minified CSS file to style my site. The combination of the two don't seem to mix well and causes all CSS styles to be removed, leaving me with a completely unstyled site (only in IE7).

I found [this link](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=253) relating to the problem but am still not sure how to solve it. It is something to do with a required whitespace after opening curly brace. I need the features of IE7js.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say try to follow the advice on the link you provided.

Open you minified CSS and add a space to the right of the opening `{`, like so

```
body{ background:#4d4d4d; //etc.

h1 strong{ color:#c2611e;  //etc.
```

Comment: That will take me hours! What do you suggest?

Comment: You could run a simple regex in your development program, something like `/(\{)/g, '$1 '` although this is untested as I am on my mobile